# Calculating pow(double,2) gives a huge number (C)

Tags: c++, montecarlo

I'm trying to code a simulation of Pi calculating using multiple processes.
I have a function that generates random double x, y numbers from 1 to -1,
and when im trying to calculate whether x^2 + y^2 <= 1,
but the result is a huge number, and its always bigger than 1.

icpi.cpp (main file):

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "main_header.h"
#include "dynamic.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

int numprocs, myid, i, root = 0, pointsInCircle = 0, pointsOutOfCircle = 0;
boolean pointInside = TRUE;
double point[DIMENSION], scatterTable[NUMBER_OF_SLAVES][DIMENSION], pi, t1, t2;
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);    
MPI_Status status;
srand(time(NULL));
t1 = MPI_Wtime();
printf("Trying to scatter..\n");
fflush(stdout);
MPI_Scatter(&scatterTable[0][0], DIMENSION, MPI_DOUBLE,     // Master process sends the first tasks to the slaves.
    &point[0], DIMENSION, MPI_DOUBLE, root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("Scatter successful\n");
fflush(stdout);
if (myid == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_NUM_OF_POINTS; i++) {
        MPI_Recv(&pointInside, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        if (pointInside) {
            pointsInCircle++;
            printf("point inside\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        else {
            pointsOutOfCircle++;
            printf("point outside\n");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        point[0] = randomPoint();       //  X component
        point[1] = randomPoint();       //  Y component
        printf("x = %f, y = %f\n", point[0], point[1]);
        fflush(stdout);
        MPI_Send(&point[DIMENSION], 2, MPI_DOUBLE, status.MPI_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    point[0] = point[1] = END_OF_PI_CALC;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SLAVES; i++)
        MPI_Send(&point[DIMENSION], 2, MPI_DOUBLE, status.MPI_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    t2 = MPI_Wtime();
    pi = calculatePi(pointsInCircle, pointsOutOfCircle);
    printf("Pi = %f.\n Time to calculate: %f", pi, (t2-t1));
}
else {
    while (point[0] != END_OF_PI_CALC || point[1] != END_OF_PI_CALC) {
        pointInside = withinCircle(point[0], point[1]);
        MPI_Send(&pointInside, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Recv(&point[DIMENSION], 2, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,     &status);
    }
}

if (myid == 0)
    MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

dynamic.cpp:

```
#include "dynamic.h"
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <math.h>
boolean withinCircle(double x, double y) {
    double result = (pow(x,(double)2) + pow(y, (double)2));
    printf("result = %f", result);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (result <= 1)
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}

double randomPoint() {
    double range = (RANDOM_MAX - RANDOM_MIN);
    double div = RAND_MAX / range;
    return RANDOM_MIN + (rand() / div);
}

double calculatePi(int pointsWithin, int pointsOutside) {
    double pi = (pointsWithin / pointsOutside) * 4;
    return pi;
}
```

dynamic.h:

```
#ifndef DYNAMIC_H
#define DYNAMIC_H

#include "main_header.h"
#define TOTAL_NUM_OF_POINTS 20000
#define NUM_OF_POINTS_TO_SEND 1 
#define RANDOM_MAX 1
#define RANDOM_MIN -1
#define NUMBER_OF_SLAVES 3
#define DIMENSION 2
#define END_OF_PI_CALC 2

boolean withinCircle(double x, double y);

double randomPoint();

double calculatePi(int pointsWithin, int pointsOutside);

#endif DYNAMIC_H
```

main_header.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


typedef int boolean;        //  Defines a boolean datatype.

#endif MAIN_H
```

example result from the wmpiexec:

```
x = -0.944151, y = 0.389386
result = 17134570711043240115048918967982918960341742262641887592820622432866394633762913354831186160392586118427086670840176838705152.000000
point outside
```

(I know the result of the actual calculation might not be right, its just an example)

Comment: This isn't enough information to help you. There are plenty of possible problems that would result in this symptom, and plenty of ways you might have misinterpreted your results. Show us your code, tell us what language you're using, tell us the specific behavior you observed (observations, not interpretations), and tell us what you expected to happen differently.

Comment: Sorry, I have just edited the question, hope its enough

Comment: What are `RANDOM_MAX` and `RANDOM_MIN`? Can you show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code - enough that we can run it and see the problem, but still stripped of as much code unrelated to the problem as possible?

Comment: First off, you have both RANDOM_MAX and RAND_MAX. Second off, rand() is *horrible* for monte carlo sims. Third off, are you absolutely sure that randomPoint actually returns a point in the correct range?

Comment: I get correct results from randomPoint() function, it returns random double numbers from -1 to 1.
What else should I use instead of rand() ?

Comment: @TLW: `RAND_MAX` is predefined in `<stdlib.h>`. I see no `#include <stdlib.h>`, which means the code in the question is incomplete. And yes, having both `RAND_MAX` and `RANDOM_MAX` is confusing.

Comment: The main_header.h has #include <stdlib.h> and dynamic.h includes main_header.h

Comment: `pow(x,(double)2)`. No need to use a cast; `pow(x, 2.0)` is clearer. And `x*x` is likely to be more efficient, and possibly more accurate, than calling `pow()`. I see no calls to `withinCircle`, so we have no idea what values you're passing. Have you tried printing (or examining in a debugger) the values of `x` and `y`?

Comment: `double pi = (pointsWithin / pointsOutside) * 4;` will result in `0`, because both variables are `int`, so it is an integer division.

Comment: And you haven't shown us `main_header.h`, so as I said the code in the question is incomplete. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: @KeithThompson I have just added the whole code.
I have run the program with wmpiexec and the values of x and y seem to be ok when the slave processes are printing them.
And obviously I need to change the pi calculation (its supposed to be PointsWithin / TotalPoints)

Comment: Minor: Rather than `double result = (pow(x,(double)2) + pow(y, (double)2));`, could use `double result = hypot(x,y);`  as code is testing against `result  <= 1.0`.

Comment: @DjangoFreeman - The issue is in the MPI code, then. Because a [stripped-down version](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9d183a855a153acd382102356ab7fcbb) works fine: `pi = 3.141631 in = 785407862, out = 214592138`

Comment: Yes, I have just tested that too and it was calculated right.

Comment: Don't put solved and an answer in your question! Add an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
double calculatePi(int pointsWithin, int pointsOutside) {
    double pi = (pointsWithin / pointsOutside) * 4;
    return pi;
}
```

This is wrong. What's happening is that you're doing an integer division and then multiplying by 4, and *then* casting it to a double. So you're getting floor behavior.

You need to cast either `pointsWithin` or `pointsOutside` to a double before you do the division.

(It's also the wrong formula, but that is another matter.)

Comment: Changed it to:
double pi = ((double)pointsWithin / (double)TOTAL_NUM_OF_POINTS) * 4.0;
But this isn't the issue, i think.
I get wrong numbers when I calculate x^2 + y^2

Comment: Suggest `double pi = 4.0 * pointsWithin / pointsOutside;`  (Avoid cast)

Answer (score 0):

I have misused MPI_Send and MPI_Recv, and now its calculating the power right.